# Barking dog reaction mechanism

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-phase-chemistry

Liebig's blue devil or the "barking dog" reaction is the gas phase oxidation of carbon disulfide with either nitrous oxide or nitric oxide.

What are the gas phase reaction steps in this reaction, I would like to know the nature of the reactive species and the mechanism of the reaction steps. If you can give me literature references to support your answer it would be much better.[barking dog reaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4TUIJhoKb4)

Comment: Seems you're rather optimistic about the knowledge about combustion reactions. I doubt we're even close to getting full mechanism. There may be some simple models though.